# How can I store and restore a force directed graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The eventual application might use AJAX to post this to the server for storage where upon they can be reloaded at a future date.

To begin I want to test the concept of saving the states of the nodes and links and reloading them without any server. I have setup a graph layout where the positions of the nodes can be moved to desired position where they remain fixed.

A 'save' button will save the state in memory, I will use the mouse the move the nodes around and then use the 'reload' button to bring it back to the previous state. My code (which is not working) is below. Please advise.

```
var storedNodes,
    storedLinks;

  var save = d3.select('.save')
    .on('mousedown', function(d){
      console.log('save pressed');
      storedNodes = JSON.stringify(force.nodes());
      storedLinks = JSON.stringify(force.links());
    });

  var restore = d3.select('.restore')
    .on('mousedown', function(d){
      console.log('restore pressed');
      force.nodes(JSON.parse(storedNodes));
      force.links(JSON.parse(storedNodes));
      force.start();
    });
```

It may also be the positioning of this code within the call to d3.json where the bulk of my code resides

Comment: are storedLinks and storedNodes defined globally?

Comment: Have you tried serialising the force layout and nodes and links?

Comment: @Jeff they are defined just above.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff please I don't quite follow please say more :)

Comment: Take the objects `force` etc, convert to JSON and store in a suitable backend.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes that it the eventual aim thanks. it should still be possible to do this without a back-end though. I will go through more examples I am sure the answer is there.

Comment: Imran, I think the point is that in the code you posted, `storedNodes` contains a *reference* to the same array that `force.nodes()` returns.  So when you "restore" the values, what you are "restoring" are the values that have been modified by dragging the nodes around with the mouse.  @LarsKotthoff is suggesting that you convert the contents of `force.nodes()`, etc. to a string containing a JSON representation of that data, and then do the restore from those strings.  You can test that method without  a real back end, and doing that should preserve the previous state.

Comment: @Mars Ok I see, almost there. I have modified the code to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to store and restore the nodes and links. Now when restore is pressed all nodes remain fixed in their new positions after the 'stored' positions are set and cannot be dragged. They do not snap back to the 'stored' positions.

Comment: I don't have anything further to suggest.  Maybe there's something obvious that's not right, but at this point I would start throwing a lot of things into `console.log()`, and also take a close look at what's in the DOM after you restore.  I wonder whether the JSON representation of the nodes is not preserving some important context.  Maybe d3 is creating SVG objects outside of the `svg` object, for example.

Comment: What happens if you add `force.stop()` before replacing the nodes and links?  (I've been working a lot with force.layout lately, but I'm still fuzzy about a lot of the details.)

Comment: @Mars no difference. When I press 'save' I also output to JSON. When I press restore all my nodes freeze, I can't drag them any more. I am reading an article on JS variable scoping to see if the problem might lie there. My code isn’t long, only 150 lines.